# Changing value of outer variable used in props after emitted listener from component disables v-model listener effects in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, eventemitter

Considering following HTML code:

```
<div id="app">
  <comp :is_checked="is_checked" v-on:ch="function(x){is_checked_2=x}"></comp>
  <p>{{ is_checked_2 }}</p>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

and *app.js*:

```
var tm = `<div>
   <input type="checkbox" v-model="is_checked"
      v-on:change="$emit('ch',is_checked)"
   >{{ is_checked }}
</div>`

Vue.component('comp', {
  template: tm,
  props: ["is_checked"]
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return { 
             is_checked: null,
             is_checked_2: null
           };
  }
});
```

If we replace `is_checked_2=x` by `console.log(x)` in `v-on:ch="function(x){...}`, everything works correct and `v-model` is changing `is_checked` when input checkbox value changes.

Also if we don't send the value of variable by props and define it locally in component, everything works correct.

> It seems that changing the parent Vue's object variable is
>   regenerating the whole HTML of component where the value of variable
>   is sent by props and the variable is reset there immediately after
>   firing the event inside template. It is causing that functions
>   triggered by events don't change component's variables.

Is it a **bug** in Vue.js?

---

---

**To make it more clear, the behavior is following: changing whatever Vue parent value that is not bound and however related to the component (no props, no slots) results at resetting all values in the component that are bound by props. Following only occurs if we reactivelly write to parent/main HTML using modified parent variable, we can achieve that by placing `{{ .... }}` there. This seems to be the bug.**

**Example:** Vue has variables `a` and `b`. We place `{{ a }}` to the main code. The value of variable `b` is sent by props to component and matched to variable `c`. With the time we are changing that value of variable `c` inside the component. In one moment we decide to change value of `a` and it results by "forgetting" current state of `c` and it is reset to initial state by invoked props.

To summarize: the bug itself gets stuck that props should be reactivelly invoked only if corresponding parent variable is changed and not if whatever parent variable changes and at the same time they modify HTML code.

**This issue doesn't have nothing to do with event listeners neither events, because it is possible to replicate it without using them.**

---

---

**Conclusion:**
`{{ is_checked_2 }}` or `{{ '',is_checked_2 }}` or `{{ '',console.log(is_checked_2) }}` after changing value of `is_checked_2` is causing rerendering the whole top Vue component having `is_checked` as variable and it is resetting child component variable, because it has the same name. **The solution is never using the same name for child and parent component variables bound by props.** This is issue of Vue/props architecture how it was designed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug.

You're most likely running into a race condition where your `change` event gets executed **before** *or* **in place of** the internally attached one (hence the seemingly nullified data binding).

Because `v-model` is essentially just a syntactic sugar for updating data on user input events. Quoting [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

> `v-model` internally uses different properties and emits different events for different input elements:
>
> - text and textarea elements use `value` property and `input` event;
> - checkboxes and radiobuttons use `checked` property and `change` event;
> - select fields use `value` as a prop and `change` as an event.

You might also want to see "[Customizing Component `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model)".

Comment: It doesn't explain different behavior for `is_checked_2=x` and `console.log(x)` in `v-on:ch="function(x){...}`. And yes, `v-model` should be fired after `change` event.

Comment: If you really believe this is a bug you'd better open an issue in the repo. This is actually quite interesting.

Comment: It is important for me to have a nice and logic code. I want to put diverse forms to many components and by filling diverse inputs/textareas there, update outer basic Vue data object with variables. I want to listen for changes of only one central data object and relativelly to them, send new data to database. If this issue isn't resolved, there is no way to achieve that.